# row.names=NULL adds a column and shifts the rest

Tags: r

When I read a txt file using

```r
read.table("text.txt", row.names=NULL, fill=TRUE)
```

a new column named "row.names" is created that takes over the values for a pre-existing column. All the rest of the columns shift to the right.

Any idea what is going on?

I used row.names=NULL, because not adding it returned error that there are duplicate row names.

The data link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bcaffo/ds4bme/master/data/federalRegions.txt

UPDATE

So this is how my data looks after read.table above:

```
   row.names        Region     State
1          1   Connecticut          
2          1         Maine          
3          1 Massachusetts          
4          1           New Hampshire
5          1         Rhode    Island
6          1       Vermont          
7          2           New    Jersey
8          2           New      York
9          3      Delaware          
10         3      Maryland          
11         3  Pennsylvania          
12         3      Virginia          
13         3          West  Virginia
14         4       Alabama          
15         4       Florida          
16         4       Georgia          
17         4      Kentucky          
18         4   Mississippi          
19         4         North  Carolina
20         4         South  Carolina
21         4     Tennessee          
22         5      Illinois          
23         5       Indiana          
24         5      Michigan          
25         5     Minnesota          
26         5          Ohio          
27         5     Wisconsin          
28         6      Arkansas          
29         6     Louisiana          
30         6           New    Mexico
31         6      Oklahoma          
32         6         Texas          
33         7          Iowa          
34         7        Kansas          
35         7      Missouri          
36         7      Nebraska          
37         8      Colorado          
38         8       Montana          
39         8         North    Dakota
40         8         South    Dakota
41         8          Utah          
42         8       Wyoming          
43         9       Arizona          
44         9    California          
45         9        Hawaii          
46         9        Nevada          
47        10        Alaska          
48        10         Idaho          
49        10        Oregon          
50        10    Washington
```

A new column "row.names" is created, overtaking "Region" values, and Region now has states as its values, and "State" now has second half of the names of the states that have two words.

Comment: The fact that it complains about duplicate row names (when you did not add `row.names=NULL`) suggests that `read.table` found that the first line had one fewer fields than the second line, suggesting that the first line was all column headers and the first field of all subsequent lines is the row name. If that's the case, then seeing duplicate row names suggests that indeed something is *wrong* with your assumption of the data. Suggestion, use `read.table(..., row.names=NULL)[,-1]` (assuming that the new column `row.names` is always prepended to be the first column, which seems true).

Comment: Or you can remove it any number of other ways, such as `dat[, setdiff(colnames(dat), "row.names")]`, or `dplyr::select(day, -row.names)`, or `subset(aaa, select=-row.names)`.

Comment: I suspect you can use `colClasses` to tell it to ignore the first column (if a `list` and any position is explicitly `NULL`, then that column is skipped), but its use requires you to know the number of columns before reading it. A double-read is not costly (esp if you read just the top few lines), but seems more work-around than perhaps necessary.

Comment: Bottom line, I don't know that there's an automatic way to omit that column using `read.table` before or while reading in; the simplest solution I suspect is to read them in to a column and then discard that column, as in my first comment.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your comments. Your recommendation may be difficult to implement, given the problem I posted on the update. If you have any suggestions, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: You have spaces in your file, therefore you cannot use `read.table` as-is.

Comment: superbot, do either of the answers address your question? If so, please accept one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AllanCameron stated, you really have a tab-delimited file with an incorrect first row. An alternative is to continue using `read.table` but skipping the first row.

```r
dat <- read.table("federalRegions.txt", sep="\t", skip=1)
head(dat)
#   V1            V2
# 1  1   Connecticut
# 2  1         Maine
# 3  1 Massachusetts
# 4  1 New Hampshire
# 5  1  Rhode Island
# 6  1       Vermont
```

You have to rename the columns, but that's not hard. You can do it manually/literally or somewhat programmatically (though this is subject to problems if there are mixed spaces/tabs).

```r
# colnames(dat) <- c("Region", "State") # manually
colnames(dat) <- strsplit(readLines("federalRegions.txt", n=1), "\\s+")[[1]]
head(dat)
#   Region         State
# 1      1   Connecticut
# 2      1         Maine
# 3      1 Massachusetts
# 4      1 New Hampshire
# 5      1  Rhode Island
# 6      1       Vermont
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a tab delimited file, but unfortunately the header row has a space instead of a tab. We can grab the file with `readLines`, change the space to a tab, and use `read.delim` to get it into a data frame:

```r
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bcaffo/ds4bme/master/data/federalRegions.txt"
text <- readLines(url)
text[1] <- gsub(" ", "\t", text[1])
df <- read.delim(text = text, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df
#>    Region          State
#> 1       1    Connecticut
#> 2       1          Maine
#> 3       1  Massachusetts
#> 4       1  New Hampshire
#> 5       1   Rhode Island
#> 6       1        Vermont
#> 7       2     New Jersey
#> 8       2       New York
#> 9       3       Delaware
#> 10      3       Maryland
#> 11      3   Pennsylvania
#> 12      3       Virginia
#> 13      3  West Virginia
#> 14      4        Alabama
#> 15      4        Florida
#> 16      4        Georgia
#> 17      4       Kentucky
#> 18      4    Mississippi
#> 19      4 North Carolina
#> 20      4 South Carolina
#> 21      4      Tennessee
#> 22      5       Illinois
#> 23      5        Indiana
#> 24      5       Michigan
#> 25      5      Minnesota
#> 26      5           Ohio
#> 27      5      Wisconsin
#> 28      6       Arkansas
#> 29      6      Louisiana
#> 30      6     New Mexico
#> 31      6       Oklahoma
#> 32      6          Texas
#> 33      7           Iowa
#> 34      7         Kansas
#> 35      7       Missouri
#> 36      7       Nebraska
#> 37      8       Colorado
#> 38      8        Montana
#> 39      8   North Dakota
#> 40      8   South Dakota
#> 41      8           Utah
#> 42      8        Wyoming
#> 43      9        Arizona
#> 44      9     California
#> 45      9         Hawaii
#> 46      9         Nevada
#> 47     10         Alaska
#> 48     10          Idaho
#> 49     10         Oregon
#> 50     10     Washington
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>